# jquery .val() (something wrong here)

Tags: jquery

I have code:

```
<input id="arrPathPhotoTop" value = < ? php echo json_encode($arrPathPhotoTop); ?> hidden>
```

Real html code is:

```
<input id="arrPathPhotoTop" value="{&quot;1&quot;:&quot;.\/files\/topface-numbers\/1.jpg&quot;,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;.\/files\/topface-numbers\/2.jpg&quot;}" hidden>
```

1)console input: $("#arrPathPhotoTop").val("www");

Output:

```
[
<input id="arrPathPhotoTop" value="{&quot;1&quot;:&quot;.\/files\/topface-numbers\/1.jpg&quot;,&quot;2&quot;:&quot;.\/files\/topface-numbers\/2.jpg&quot;}" hidden >
]
```

2)console input:
$("#arrPathPhotoTop").val();

Output:
"www"

**Result**: code html didnt cange but "real" value have beed changed. Is it ok?

Example img: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1hkN.jpg

**CHECK IT**: http://jsfiddle.net/nywuctuk/S9mUL/1702/ **WTF?**

**real ANSWER is:** *hidden* chaned to *type="hidden"*

http://jsfiddle.net/nywuctuk/S9mUL/1703/

*p.s. The name of site must be changed like "help yourself"  :D*

Answer (score 1):

Jquery's `.val()` will change the value property of that element object internally. That means it will not reflect those changes in the value attribute of `HTML`. This is a natural behaviour of how `.val()` works. If you want to get or set the `value attribute` present with html string then you need to use `.attr()`

Answer (score 0):

The 'value' tag governs the original value when the page is loaded, but is mostly irrelevant afterwards; you've correctly updated the value, but that won't change the original HTML. You can pretty much ignore the HTML-specified initial value now.